# Google Cloud API: EOFError: Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I have some really simple Python code that I'm using to do a GCP Google Vault export. However, about 4 out of ever 5 runs returns an EOF Error. The stacktrace is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/initiate_job.py", line 57, in <module>
    results = service.matters().list(pageSize=10).execute()
  File "/Users/ipq500/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 134, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ipq500/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 901, in execute
    headers=self.headers,
  File "/Users/ipq500/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 177, in _retry_request
    resp, content = http.request(uri, method, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ipq500/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google_auth_httplib2.py", line 190, in request
    self._request, method, uri, request_headers)
  File "/Users/ipq500/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/auth/credentials.py", line 133, in before_request
    self.refresh(request)
  File "/Users/ipq500/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/oauth2/service_account.py", line 359, in refresh
    access_token, expiry, _ = _client.jwt_grant(request, self._token_uri, assertion)
  File "/Users/ipq500/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/oauth2/_client.py", line 153, in jwt_grant
    response_data = _token_endpoint_request(request, token_uri, body)
  File "/Users/ipq500/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/oauth2/_client.py", line 105, in _token_endpoint_request
    response = request(method="POST", url=token_uri, headers=headers, body=body)
  File "/Users/ipq500/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google_auth_httplib2.py", line 117, in __call__
    url, method=method, body=body, headers=headers, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ipq500/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1994, in request
    cachekey,
  File "/Users/ipq500/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1651, in _request
    conn, request_uri, method, body, headers
  File "/Users/ipq500/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1621, in _conn_request
    content = _decompressContent(response, content)
  File "/Users/ipq500/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 460, in _decompressContent
    content = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=io.BytesIO(new_content)).read()
  File "/Users/ipq500/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/gzip.py", line 276, in read
    return self._buffer.read(size)
  File "/Users/ipq500/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/gzip.py", line 482, in read
    raise EOFError("Compressed file ended before the "
EOFError: Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached
```

The code that throws this is just:

```
service = build('vault', 'v1', credentials=delegated_credentials)
results = service.matters().list(pageSize=10).execute()
```

I tried to add some defensive programming wherein I simply retry anything that throws this error -- but now I'm hitting rate limits. So, I have to really debug why I'm getting this error.

Any and all help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [question](https://www.tutorialfor.com/questions-69334.htm) and this [conversation](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/g/anaconda/c/WxOAThwVwvg), It seems that the file that you read is damaged and the error of end of the file is expected, In this case I suggest to verify if the credentials exist, take the [sample](https://developers.google.com/vault/quickstart/python#step_3_set_up_the_sample) as references and also try to perform a double check before to perform any task, On the other hand, it does the same with the file for the file since it is possible that the writing of the file is not finished, including whether it is being compressed or decompressed